# How to fetch file present in flyway.locations folder from PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, flyway

I've requirement such that need to read an xlsx file from flyway locations through pl/sql procedure, end objective is to store the xlsx file as blob in the database, any inputs on how to achieve this.

Comment: Need more details

Comment: Yeah, how does the xlsx files relate to flyway locations? https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/locations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.